# How do I fix the 'cannot load such file -- .../laravel/homestead/scripts/homestead.rb' error

Tags: php, laravel, vagrant

When using Vagrant `up` or `halt` I get the error `There was an error loading a Vagrantfile`

I setup a local Homestead server using the per project installation guide in the [Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/homestead#per-project-installation) without running into any problems. While working on my project I deleted a field in Craft CMS which refreshed the page to an error.

I tried using the `halt` command to stop the server which returned the error message below. So I was forced to "manually" power off the server in Virtualbox.

The error I get when I run `vagrant up` or `vagrant halt`:

```
cannot load such file -- /Users/.../.../.../.../.../vendor/laravel/homestead/scripts/homestead.rb
```

*Replaced some of the items to shorten the line

I checked the path in my project and noticed the entire `/laravel` folder is missing.

The last thing I did in the terminal was check the composer version. I have no idea what could have caused the laravel folder to just disappear but is there a way to "rollback" or "refresh" vagrant instead of reinstalling it all?

I'm running Vagrant version `2.2.5` and Composer version `1.8.6`

Comment: I fixed the error by updating composer using the `composer update` command. This however somehow broke my `homestead.yaml` mapping...

Answer (score 0):

If you ever run into this problem where you're suddenly missing your `/laravel` folder. Try running `composer update` in your project. You might have to fix your `homestead.yaml` mapping settings (might be specific to my situation but I had to change the folder root) but I got it up and running again.